# Android linking more than one xml to java class file

Tags: android, manifest, swipe

I have implemented horizontal page view. One base page and three swipe pages.
The base page is linked to the java class file. But there are actions in swipe pages. for eg: button click. How do i do it? Can i link the swipe pages to the same java class file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean...

1 - Are you searching for a way to use an xml file as child in your swiper?

This can be done using a LayoutInflater

2 - This is already done but you can't find out how to control certain events?

If you have inflated the views using the LayoutInflater you can access that Views children:

```
childView.findViewById(R.id.btn1).setOnClickListener(...);
```

OR

You can add the onClick attribute in xml and implement that in your main activity ie:

`xml: onClick="btn1pressed"`

`java: public void btn1pressed(View v) {}`

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that you have 3 .xml layouts, and one class that extends Activity?

Do the layouts together form one page? If they do, you can compose them together using the `include` tag. Here's a post on the android blog on the topic,

> http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-2-reusing-layouts.html

Another option is to use fragments to compose "sub views", then use the activity class to compose them into a one page. fragments allow you to encapsulate the view (.xml) and the controller (the click handlers, etc) into a single unit (the fragment).

> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html

If the 3 .xml layouts describe three separate pages, you need to have 3 activities, one backing each layout.

Comment: its horizontal pageview. Something like the default application list in android devices, where you can swipe pages containing apps. each swipe page is seperate xml page, which is embedded on a base page, which is linked to the java class file. And i have buttons on swipe pages whose events cannot be detected because it returns null when findViewById.

Comment: in that case, it makes sense to have a single activity (or fragment) handling the whole thing. how to implement something like that is beyond the scope of what can be posted here. i'd recommend pulling the AOSP source and looking for useful code you can copy from there.

Answer (score 1):

See my question/answer that has nearly the same exact context [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522928/displaying-multiple-xml-views-w-o-fragments) Just get it to display a single xml and then add the switches as I did there.